# Правильный подбор падежа

Tags: падежи

Здравствуйте. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с правильным подбором падежа.

> Парень делится с друзьями странными рассказами о каком-то
>   неопределенном чудовище, которое каждый описывает по-своему.

"Которое" или "которого"?

Начав плотно работать с текстами, я заметил, что с падежами довольно часто возникает путаница.

Например:

> Дерево было старым/старое.

Существует ли какое-то правило для таких ситуаций, или сам автор выбирает, какой падеж "уместнее" в каждом конкретном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Парень делится с друзьями странными рассказами о каком-то неопределенном чудовище, которое (В.п., ед .число) каждый описывает по-своему**.

Чудовище - одуш. сущетвительное, но категория одушевленности для сущ. ср. рода  выражена только во мн. числе: вижу чудовище (форма В.п. совпдает с формой И.п.) и вижу чудовищ (форма В.п. совпдает с формой Р.п.).

В вашем примере используется форма ед. числа, поэтому В.п. совпадает с И.п., категория одушевленности не выражена.

**2) Дерево было старым/старое.** Здесь возможно колебание при выборе падежа, но лучше подойдет вариант "Дерево **было старое**", так как И.п. связан с постоянным признаком. Сравнить: Деревья **стали большими** (меняющийся признак выражен Т.п.).

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь понял.

Comment: Про постоянные и меняющиеся признаки... Старое дерево – постоянный признак, а большое дерево – меняющийся? Дерево старилось, старилось – и стало старым. Росло, росло – и выросло, т.е. стало большим. В чем разница?

Comment: @Niemand  Объяснение для детского сада: старое дерево так и будет всё время старым (признак постоянный). А большое дерево может еще вырасти.

Comment: @Niemand и  Sibylla , по-моему вы не туда завернули. "Стало большим/старым" - есть динамика, "было большое/старое" - нет динамики

Comment: А я тут при чем? У меня примеры такие: дерево было старое, деревья стали большими. Но здесь нет однозначного соответствия  для было/стало,  например: "Жадов наморщил кожу на лбу, лицо его покрылось мелкими неожиданными морщинами, СТАЛО СТАРОЕ. [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам  (1922)]

Comment: @Sibylla  Как я понимаю, Ваш п.2 носит рекомендательный характер, а Толстой пошел другим путем )))

Comment: Да, в каждом конкретном случае могут влиять разные факторы, также следует учесть, что в современном языке Т.п. используется чаще, чем это было раньше. Розенталь  §179. Формы сказуемого. п. 3 http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm